# Remove duplicated table column incl. table head to new table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, duplicates, cell

I've tried different workarounds and modified some scripts but I can't do it in the way I'd like to

I've a table and all duplicated columns (inclusive the additional table th) should be moved to an table 2 ... only the different columns should be stay in table 1

```
<table width="200" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">Colour</th>
  <th scope="col">Weight</th>
  <th scope="col">Width</th>
  <th scope="col">Size</th>
  <th scope="col">Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>black</td>
  <td>20kg</td>
  <td>10cm</td>
  <td>XL</td>
  <td>20,90€</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>green</td>
  <td>20kg</td>
  <td>8cm</td>
  <td>XL</td>
  <td>20,90€</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>red</td>
  <td>20kg</td>
  <td>5cm</td>
  <td>XL</td>
  <td>10,00€</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Any snippet or possible workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by a duplicate column? A duplicate header or every value in a column is the same?

Comment: if there is just one duplicated cell-content in the same row, these should move into table 2. only different attributes (cell content) should stay in table one ... for example 1 => all weights are the same => move to table 2 incl. row <th> 

for example 2 => price 1 and price 2 are the same => move to table 2 incl. row <th> but leave different price 3 in table one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a snippet to get started

```
$("table tbody tr").each(function (index, option)
            {
                var FirstColumnVal = $(this)[0].cells[0].innerText;
                var SecondColumnVal = $(this)[0].cells[1].innerText;
                $("table tbody tr").each(function (index1, option1)
                {
                    // Avoid same column comparision    
                    if(index != index1)
                    {
                        // 1st Column Check
                        if ($(this)[0].cells[0].innerText == FirstColumnVal)
                        {
                            // duplicate found - remove element or move to other table
                        }

                        // 2nd Column Check 
                        if ($(this)[0].cells[1].innerText == SecondColumnVal) {
                            // duplicate found - remove element or move to other table

                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Do the same for other columns.

Comment: great :) thanks!! i'll try ... but right now i get an error => Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Comment: You can apparently use either outerText or innerHTML. Both of them would give you the value you expect.